# Return values in JavaScript functions

Tags: javascript

I was reviewing variable accessibility in functions vs. the global scope and came across something new and wondered if the following is correct:

```
function foo (){
    message='Hi'
}
alert(message); //ReferenceError: message is not defined
```

This returns an error because `foo` hasn't been called anywhere yet, but once you do, it's available in the global space. Got it.

However I read somewhere besides explicitly making functions return a value (i.e. using the return keyword) we use them for their side-effects (e.g. imagine I put that alert function inside foo I just referenced).

So is the above somehow returning the value the same way it would when using the `return` keyword?

**UPDATE**
I am getting a lot of feedback but perhaps I should restate the question.
Is the mere fact of calling the function putting it in the global scope.
Like what is happening behind the scenes...? I think some people may think (as I did) by simply omitting the var, it's in the global scope. Actually, for those who don't know, you have to call the function first.
THANKS!

Comment: It is hard to figure out what you mean. What one normally would do is `function foo (){
    return 'Hi';
}
alert(foo());`

Comment: The function `foo` is not returning any value because it doesn't have a `return` keyword.  It might have side effects like adding a value to the global scope, but this is different than returning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So is the above somehow returning the value the same way it would when using the return keyword?

No. It's relying on the [*Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) by assigning to a variable that isn't declared anywhere. When you do that, in loose mode, it creates a global variable. It's nothing to do with returning a value from a function, and it's nothing that you should do — in fact, this is one of the better reasons to use strict mode and/or a "lint" tool like JSHint, so that inadvertent globals become errors you can find and fix.

To return a value from a function, you:

1. Use `return` in the function to say what to return and when, e.g.:

   ```
   function myFunction() {
       return "foo";
   }
   ```
2. Use the result of the function when you call it, e.g.:

   ```
   var variable = myFunction();
   // or
   anotherFunction(myFunction());
   // etc.
   ```

Example of the difference assigning to an undeclared variable in loose mode and strict mode:

```js
function runLoose() {
  // In loose mode
  try {
    looseFoo = "bar";
    snippet.log(looseFoo); // "bar"
  }
  catch (e) {
    snippet.log("Got exception: " + e.message);
  }
}

function runStrict() {
  "use strict";
  
  // In strict mode
  try {
    strictFoo = "bar"; // <== Causes ReferenceError
    snippet.log(strictFoo);
  }
  catch (e) {
    snippet.log("Got exception: " + e.message);
  }
}

runLoose();
runStrict();
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

No, nothing is returned.

If you call foo first, message is defined because variables declared without var are global in scope.

If you add var it no longer has global scope and you get the same error.

```
function foo (){
    var message='Hi'
}
foo();
alert(message); //ReferenceError: message is not defined
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no...

You have access to variables which are in parent-scopes through something known as closure.

```
function a () {
  var aValue = 1;
  console.log(aValue); // 1
  function b () {
    aValue += 1;
  }
  console.log(aValue); // 1
  b();
  console.log(aValue); // 2
}
```

This works because when you define a function (the place where the source-code is actually written in the file), that function is given reference to all of the variables in its parent's scope (and its parent's, et cetera, up to `window`).

`window`, itself, is a ...special-case function, as far as variables are concerned.

Think of it like b.**secretTable**.parent.**secretTable**.aVar += 1;

...you hit a reference error when you run out of `.parent` elements to climb up, and you still haven't found that variable name anywhere.

Relying on the scope-tables for setting undeclared variables on `window` (if you set a value to a variable, it climbs up that scope chain, until it finds the scope where the var was declared, or it runs out of `.parent` elements...  ...which is `window`, and then sets the value there) is approximately the worst thing, ever.

...relying on closure references, in general, is fantastic, in controlled ways, though.

Relying on tight closure references (building thunks / currying functions / et cetera) is key for JavaScript that doesn't look like Java.

Answer (score -1):

It's not returning anything. It's just changing the value of a "global" variable.

```
var test = 0; // global scope
function foo() {
    var localVar = 'bar'; // local to function
    test = 1; // accessing/modifying global "test" var
}
foo();
alert(test);     // alerts "1"
alert(localVar); // ReferenceError: localVar is not defined
```

To break it down, the first variable `test` was created within global scope.  It is accessed within the `foo()` function and changed.  After calling said function, `alert()` on that variable outputs the value set within the function.  (no return necessary because it's global).

On the other hand, `localVar` is created within the function and therefore alerting it results in a `ReferenceError`, this is because that variable only exists within the function.

Exact result can be replicated in the jsFiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/z1xpvs5j/

Comment: You don't call `foo()` - most of the above is incorrect.

Comment: @Archer incorrect? I beg to differ. The `localVar` was just to demonstrate and have an excuse to put the comment briefly explaining a local-to-function variable and its scope.  The missing `foo()` was an honest mistake. 3 downvotes?  Weak.  I ran my code after adding in the missing `foo()` (which was just me being forgetful and fast) and everything was as expected and annotated in my code comments.  Again, "incorrect?" I beg to differ, pal.  In the end, my answer _is_ correct and _is_ helpful.  Should it be the highest voted and accepted answer? Maybe not.  But does it deserve 3 down votes? No

Comment: Dude, this isn't a forum.  If you don't like something then that's fine, but let's not start flaming each other, yeah?  Now that you've fixed it I will remove the one and only -1 I gave you.  That's how this site works.  The points aren't there for you - they're there for other people, so don't take it personally.  At the time of writing my -1 and comment were correct.

Comment: @Archer fine and fair enough.  However, my points about reputation are still true (and incidentally not at all personal toward you).  I'm fully aware this isn't a forum as I have been using and participating heavily on this site for almost 5 years.  Just never received so many down votes for something so trivial and small.

Comment: In fairness, the way you originally posted it was wrong.  People come and go and quite rightly downvote things that don't help.  I've had it myself.  Anyway 2 downvotes and 1 upvote (now that it's correct) turn it into positive points, so don't worry about it.

Comment: @Archer Yes that's true too.  I answered quickly and left my computer when I went for food and came back hours later.  Thanks, anyway.  I don't care so much about points, I just was like: ok here I am trying to help and people are like "nope, wrong." lol  Whatever, I'm over it.  Cheers